# Wagtail: Adding an Orderable class to an Orderable class

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a snippet that uses an Orderable class. I would like to add another Orderable class to the first Orderable. For example:

```
models.py:

@register_snippet
class LocationHours(ClusterableModel):
    location = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Location for this set of Hours.'
    )

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('location'),
            InlinePanel('location_hours'),
        ], "Hours"),
    ]

class Hours(Orderable):
    snippet = ParentalKey('LocationHours', related_name='location_hours', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ...

    panels = [
        ...
        InlinePanel('hours_override', label="Hours Overrides"),
    ]

class HoursOverride(Orderable):
        orderable = ParentalKey('Hours', related_name='hours_override', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: did you try orderable with blocks ?

Comment: @waLLe Can you add a Streamfield to a Snippet?

Comment: I have to check, didn't try